# Using software OpenGL rendering with X

Tags: xorg, opengl

I want to try the most basic OpenGL driver, in order to find out what's the problem of my X server with OpenGL.

I want then to have X use software rendering for OpenGL, like windows do with `opengl.dll` with no driver installed.

How can I do that? Didn't find anything when searching for `X OpenGL software rendering`. I'll be glad for a reference, and for the keywords I had to use in order to find out how to do that.

I'm using `Xorg` in RHEL 5.3.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/106056/force-software-based-opengl-rendering

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Duplicating my answer [Force software based opengl rendering - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/106056/force-software-based-opengl-rendering/210381#210381):

> ```
> sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-swx11
> ```
>
> will remove the [`libgl1-mesa-glx`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/libgl1-mesa-glx) hardware-accelerated Mesa libraries and install the software-only renderer.
>
> Alternately, you can set `LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1`, which will only affect programs started with that environment variable, not the entire system.

Fedora doesn't package the `swrast` DRI backend separately from `mesa-dri-drivers` (and I assume the same is the case in RHEL), so the first isn't an option, but the latter is.

Comment: But do you have to remove the package? Can't you just remove a line from xorg.conf?

Comment: I hadn't thought of that — many newer distributions have a skeleton or no `xorg.conf` at all, so I'd have to explain which `Section` to add/change and what lines to add/change within there — but RHEL is old enough that you could probably flip the DRI extension by changing a single line from Load to Disable.

Comment: see my answer for a simpler approach. I don't care about loading the DRI module, I just want to avoid using it ;-).

Answer (score 2):

Another simpler solution is to add `Option NoDRI`, to the `Device` section in `xorg.conf`. For example

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Generic Video Card"
    Driver      "savage"
    BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
    Option      "NoDRI"
EndSection
```

According to [this email](http://www.redhat.com/archives/fedora-devel-list/2006-September/msg00593.html), it should always work. See [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-savage/+bug/65197) for more information. I didn't find anything about it in Xorg's documentation, so if you find anything about it - do edit it into my answer.

Comment: I believe that doesn't work for all drivers, but if it works for you, then good.

Comment: Please see the first link, if it doesn't work for your driver - file a bug. http://www.redhat.com/archives/fedora-devel-list/2006-September/msg00593.html

Comment: `NoDRI` is basically the same as `LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT` environment variable I believe. But this variable isn't quite the same as `LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE`: it even gives lower OpenGL version for me on Intel(R) HD Graphics P4600/P4700.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [Mesa](http://www.mesa3d.org/).  I'm not sure if RHEL has RPMs for that.  (Although Mesa is used in some hardware OpenGL drivers for X, it also provides a software-only renderer.)

Comment: Mesa is perfectly installed in RHEL. However how do I instruct X to use the Mesa *software rendering* instead of DRI?

Comment: Look in the xorg.conf file for DRI and set it to not be enabled.